# how to resize and convert video to MPEG-4 (mp42 codec) FFmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm using [`FFmpegAndroid`](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) for resizing and converting videos. I'm using following command to resize / convert my videos.

```
"-i", <INPUT_PATH>.mp4, "-vf", "scale=720:1280", "-c:v", "libx264", "-x264-params", "bluray-compat=1:force-cfr=1", <OUTPUT_PATH>.mp4
```

The result I got is `isom` video codec. what I want is `mp42` video codec.

Thanks.

Comment: `isom` and `mp42` are brands, not codec.

Comment: @Gyan you saved my day. Thanks for the information.